# Unittesting with laravel, call with Json parameter

Tags: json, unit-testing, laravel

I'm trying to make a put call with a json object as parameter from a testclass. How can I do this? I can't find anything in the documentation. If I make the same call with the Chrome Advanced Rest Client and the exact same json object it works. But I don't know how to call from the test, because if i call with the Json Object then it says its not allowed to call with String, if I try it with an array it says "UnexpectedValueException: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given."
Please help me, I'm freaking out. :)

```
    $data = array("text" => "unit_test");
    $jsonData = json_encode($data);

    $this->call('PUT','stomt/1', array('{"text" : "test"}'));
    //or
    $this->call('PUT','stomt/1', $jsonData);
    //or
    $this->call('PUT','stomt/1',array($jsonData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $this->call('PUT','stomt/1', array("text" => "test"));
```

Your idea was correct but the way that you created the array is not. IE:

```
    array('{"text" : "test"}')
```

will not create an array correctly in PHP.

Comment: thank you very much, but it still throws the same exception. If I do a get oder delete call everything works fine, but as soon as I try to post or put something it does not work.

Comment: Hey, could you paste in the error that you get when you execute the above code?

Comment: The Error is in the question, its "UnexpectedValueException: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given."

Comment: That error suggests to me that the PUT call to 'stomt/1' is not returning a string. Where does that route point to? The TestCase call method returns an Illuminate\Http\Response object, which expects it's contents to be String.

So, double check the method that the PUT route to 'stomt/1' calls. Does it return a string or a boolean? If it returns anything but a string you must change the return value (or rethink your testing strategy). Hope this works!